# while loop to restrict the number of downloaded files continues beyond conditional parameters

Tags: r, bash

I want to download a large number of ftp files. I made a list file that contain the links of the thousands of ftp. FTP download results in 'gbff.gz' files. Now say for some reason I want to restrict the number of downloaded files (with .gz extension) in current directory to 5.

To test that I made a while loop in R that use bash system command:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/test")
a<-system('find . | grep -i ".gz$" |wc -l')
while (a<5) {
  system('wget -nc -tries=1 -i list.txt')
}
```

But seems like the while loop is not working. I mean, ideally it should break the loop when the number of .gz files in current directory is more than 5, but the download continues for all links in list file.

N.B.- My apologies for making such a hybrid script. As I already working in R it seems easy to me. I would also appreciate any alternate bash/awk/sed script if that is more suitable for this.

N.B2- FYI, I use -nc tag in wget, so a re-download of an already existing file should not occur.

Comment: Assuming the regular expression is correct, you will need to update `a` within the loop not outside it.

Comment: You can find number of files in a folder using `length(list.files(pattern = "\\.gz$"))`.